# No matching index found on DateTimeProperty Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, indexing

I'm using Google App Engine, Python and I'm building a feature that allows user to order their photos by the number of votes or creation_date.

**The models should look like:**

```
class MyUser(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty(required=True)
    name = db.StringProperty()
class UserImage(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(MyUser,collection_name='user_images')

    image_key = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty(required=False)
    creation_date = db.DateTimeProperty(required=True,auto_now_add=True)
    votes = db.IntegerProperty(required=False)
```

**Two queries I would like to run:**

```
my_user = db.get('my_user_key')
1) image_keys = my_user.user_images.order('-votes').fetch(100,keys_only=True)
2) image_keys = my_user.user_images.order('-creation_date').fetch(100,keys_only=True)
```

The first query runs just fine but the second gives me *NeedIndexError: no matching index found* even when I add those properties into **index.yaml**

**Here is my index.yaml**

```
indexes:
- kind: UserImage
  properties:
  - name: user
  - name: votes
    direction: desc
  - name: creation_date
    direction: desc
```

Google App Engine Dashboard tells me that **all indexes are serving** right now.

---

**UPDATE**

What I wrote in the index.yaml actually Order By votes then by creation_date. As suggested by dragonx. I split them out and it works as expected.

---

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separate indexes

```
indexes:
- kind: UserImage
  properties:
  - name: user
  - name: votes
    direction: desc

- kind: UserImage
  properties:
  - name: user
  - name: creation_date
    direction: desc
```

Comment: Remember that this will also double the number of writes when you put() so don't complain later on that your app costs you too much :)